# Best way to make links clickable in block of text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want:

> ```
> Here is link: http://google.com
> And http://example.com inside.
> And another one at the very end: http://test.net
> ```

to become:

> ```
> Here is link: <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
> And <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> inside.
> And another one at the very end: <a href="http://test.net">http://test.net</a>
> ```

Seems like a trivial task, but I cannot find a PHP function that works. Do you have any ideas?

```
function make_links_clickable($text){
    // ???
}

$text = 'Here is link: http://google.com
And http://example.com inside.
And another one at the very end: http://test.net';

echo make_links_clickable($text);
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use this (works with ftp, http, ftps and https schemes):

```
function make_links_clickable($text){
    return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
}
```

Comment: what are the `!` that you placed at the beginning and end of the regexp?

Comment: What are the non-ASCII characters in your regex? ('я' and 'Я')?

Comment: @NeilHillman: They are included to support Cyrillic domain names (both the А and Я are Cyrillic) [More Info](http://www.rferl.org/content/Cyrillic_Domain_Names_Become_Operational_On_The_Internet/2041131.html) • [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.%D1%80%D1%84)

Comment: This wont work with links that dont start with http://. I'd suggest adding a str_replace looking for www. and adding http:// infront. Then i'd add another str_replace checkign for double htt p: //htt p : // to replace that with one

Comment: @Akarun what if the link is like this? `(https://www.sample.com/request).`  The function will include the ")" and "." at the end and it look like this `<a href="https://www.sample.com/request).">https://www.sample.com/request).</a>`

Comment: Any way to make this work based on if the link text is wrapped in a certain class or ID?

Comment: Just remove the two () brackets and it won't put the closing bracket into the url anymore (https://example.com). I am not aware of a valid URL that contains brackets? `!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i`

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  The `(s)` is just as good as `s`.  `[a-zA-Z0-9_] is the same as `\w`.

Answer (score 6):

```
function makeClickableLinks($text)
{
$text = html_entity_decode($text);
$text = " ".$text;
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)([\w]*?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"$3\" >$3</a>", $text);  
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|wap)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"http://$3\" >$3</a>", $text);
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ftp)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"$4://$3\" >$3</a>", $text);  
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2@$3\">$2@$3</a>", $text);  
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])(mailto:[a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1<a href=\"$2@$3\">$2@$3</a>", $text);  
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])(skype:[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/i", "$1<a href=\"$2\">$2</a>", $text);  
        return $text;
}
```

work with:

www.example.com

https://www.example.com

http://www.example.com

wap.example.com

ftp.example.com

user@example.com

skype:example

mailto:user@example.com

atherprotocol://example.com

Comment: These successive waves of replacements are in no way explained.  This answer is incomplete and anyone who is to use this answer is probably copy-pasting with blind faith.  This answer should be edited to be more generous/educational.  There should be ONLY one `preg_replace()` call; there should be an array of pattern and an array of replacements.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
function make_links_clickable($text)
{
   return preg_replace ('/http:\/\/[^\s]+/i', "<a href=\"${0}\">${0}</a>", $text);
} 

$result = make_links_clickable($text);
```

Comment: Solutions provided in links suggested by Akarun and by Lawrence Cherone are more complete becaus they check the url to ba a valid url, they detects also https and ftp links, they urldecode links before showing them. My solution is more dirty, but it shoudl work for simple tasks.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Also inspired by Akarun's answer, the following function will turn to links only the text that is not already a link. The added functionality is checking that a link with the captured text link doesn't already exists in the target string:

```
function make_links_from_http($content) {   
    // Links out of text links
    preg_match_all('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', $content, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key=>$link) {
        if (!preg_match('!<a(.*)'.$link.'(.*)/a>!i', $content))
        {
            $content = str_replace($link, '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$link.'</a>', $content);
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

By testing, I noticed that the above function fails on line #5. A "messier" function that does the job is the following:

```
function make_links_from_http($content) 
{
    // The link list
    $links = array();

    // Links out of text links
    preg_match_all('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', $content, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key=>$link) 
    {
        $links[$link] = $link;
    }

    // Get existing
    preg_match_all('/<a\s[^>]*href=([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU', $content, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[2] as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (isset($links[$value]))
        {
            unset($links[$value]);
        }
    }

    // Replace in content
    foreach ($links as $key=>$link)
    {
        $content = str_replace($link, '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$link.'</a>', $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

For the new code, I have used the tutorial at:
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/

Comment: When you need to perform a `preg_` call nested inside of a `preg_` call, this typically indicates that the first regex pattern was not well crafted.  When you are matching occurrences only to iterate and replace what is matched, this typically indicates that you should have used `preg_replace_callback()`.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Akarun's answer I came up with tis function to handle all protocols and links that start with only `www.`

```
function make_links($text, $class='', $target='_blank'){
    return preg_replace('!((http\:\/\/|ftp\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)|www\.)([-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?!ism', 
    '<a class="'.$class.'" href="//$3" target="'.$target.'">$1$3</a>', 
    $text);
}
```

This function has optional parameters to add class names onto the links and also optional target for the link, so they open on new window/tab... by default the parameter opens links to new window/tab, but if you feel like not doing that, you can change default, or change the value when calling the function.

Comment: This pattern is overwhelmingly bloated with unnecessary escaping in the pattern.  Ask yourself why you are using the `s` pattern modifier if there are no `.` (any character "dots") in the pattern.  Then ask yourself why you are using the `m` pattern modifier if there are no `^` or `$` (anchors) in the pattern. `http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/` is unnecessarily verbose. `a-zA-Zа-яА-Я` is unnecesarily verbose. I would not recommend that anyone use this snippet -- even if it delivers the intended results because it is not teaching best practices.