# How to get a url from a database

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

So I have three pages one that is the index page. One that writes the data from a form inside the index page to the database. And one that gets data from the database and echos out a html table with the data inside.

Currently if you write a link in the form. It will just come out as text. I would like the whole link to be like `<a href="[link]">[link]</a>`.

so say if I wrote this onto the form:

Look at this: www.google.com *or* Look at this: https://www.google.com

it would come out like this in html

Look at this: `<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>`

How could I go about doing this?

---

Okay so the html is:

```
<form class="wide" action="Write-to.php" method="post">
        <input class="wide" autocomplete="off" name="txt" type="text" id="usermsg" style="font-size:2.4vw;" value=""  />
</form>
```

in which the user would write:

"Look at this: www.google.com *or* Look at this: https://www.google.com"

This would then get sent to the database through `Write-to.php`.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO social (comunicate)

VALUES

('$_POST[txt]')";
}
```

this then gets written back into the database:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"(select * from social order by id desc limit {$limit_amt}) order by id asc");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
      echo "<tr div id='".$i."' class='border_bottom'>";
      echo "<th scope='col'>";
      echo "<span class='text'>".htmlspecialchars($row['comunicate'])."</span><br />";
      echo "</th>";
      echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your code about echoing the url?

Comment: It is just the standard way using mysqli `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: If you post the code we might help you

Comment: Is that okay @Fabio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
echo('<a href="'.$your_url_variable.'">'.$your_url_variable.'</a>');
```

Update:

The OP really wanted to detect url's in a string. One possible solution could be filter it using a regular expression. This code could help:

```
<?php

// The Regular Expression filter
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

// The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com";

// Check if there is a url in the text
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {

       // make the urls hyper links
       echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href="{$url[0]}">{$url[0]}</a> ", $text);

} else {

       // if no urls in the text just return the text
       echo $text;

}
?>
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/

Comment: I know how to create the link! I just need a way for the php to recognise that part of it **is** a link

Comment: Filter it using a regular expression. Take a look at this link: [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Copy and paste it into your answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things you need to worry about when displaying user supplied (tainted) data.

- You must ensure that all the data is sanitised -- never ***ever*** just echo the content, look into [htmspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) and [FILTER_VALIDATE_URL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) for example:

> ```
> function validateUrl($url) {
>     return filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); 
> }
> ```

- What you are attempting to do is convert a string into a link, for example you can write a function like this:

> ```
> function makeClickable($link) {
>     $link = htmlspecialchars($link);
>     return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $link, $link);
> }
> ```

- You can use string concatenation as well, but I wouldn't do that in my view code.  Just personal preference.
- Take a look at the [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function, it will certainly come in handy.
- I would also recommend you read about [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Please note that I am not making any implementation recommendations, my aim is just to show you some contrived code samples that demonstrate making a string "clickable".

Update:
If you would like to make links clickable within text, refer to the following questions:

- [Best way to make links clickable in block of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341168/best-way-to-make-links-clickable-in-block-of-text)
- [Replace URLs in text with HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links)

Comment: +1 because useful info. But not really answering the question. So not sure if I am abiding the law here

Comment: My "makeClickable" function will make a valid user supplied link clickable, there are a few cases you will need to cater for, for example are you sure you're always going to get valid urls? Sometimes users don't bother with http:// etc.  The best I can do is give you a contrived simple demo and you can adapt it to your use case :)

Answer (score 0):

save the hyperlink in db and retrieve as a string by sql query 
like:

`select link from table_name  where index = i`
and save link as:`<a href="whatever"> whaatever here</a>`

and print it

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this
echo '<a href="' . $res['url'] . '">' . $res['url'] . '</a>';
```