# PHP - Replacing URL's in text with links, but only if they're not already tagged

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for a way to modify this function, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5341330/9299892), so that it doesn't change the tags I already have.

```
function make_links_clickable($text){
return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);}
```

For example, while it works great at turning regular text into links, it also turns this:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</a>
```

Into this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow
```

As I'm a beginner, and not very familiar with regexp, I'd appreciate it if there was a simple solution to this that doesn't require making the code a lot more complicated than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?<!href=["'])(?P<link>https?:\/\/(?:(?P<subdomain>(?:.*?\.)*?)(?P<domain>[^.]*))(?P<tld>\.[^.\n]+|\.co\.[^\/]+)(?P<path>(?:\/.*?|)))$
```

Using this regex and substitution, you should be able to do this.

Check it out on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MTaipr/4)

In the substitution, I've done this:

```
<a href="${link}">${domain}</a>
```

Which turns these:

```
https://stackoverflow.com
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news
```

Into these:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
<a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news">bbc</a>
```

But does not touch this:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```

If you want to do more with the other items, you can do, and I capture as much as I can so that you can mould this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there exist a couple of duplicate questions but I cannot immediately find one (Note: *I'm willing to close the question if someone provides a dupe link*).

The answer is most probably to use a parser instead but for a quick & dirty solution you could as well use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` as in:

```
<a[^>]+>.+?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(?:ftp|https?)://\S+
```

This needs to be replaced by

```
<a href="$0">$0</a>
```

---

The idea here is to match what you don't want, e.g. anything that looks like a link:

```
<a[^>]+>.+?</a>
```

And then to "throw the match away" and provide an alternative.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/po6UM1/1).